# how to access to Azure time series insights through API without any application registered?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, postman, azure-timeseries-insights

I want to access (read & write data) to azure time series insight through the api without registering any application. My job is it send/push the jmeter result to azure time series insight, is there any way to do it as I don't have access to create/register any application for it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

You **must** register an application. This is how you tell Azure AD that you intent to talk to Azure service that is being protected by Azure AD. These are the rules of engagement, and a standard protocol flow (e.g. OpenID Connect / OAuth require a *client* registration).

This is explicitly documented in the relevant [Authentication & Authorization for Time Series Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/time-series-insights-authentication-and-authorization) docs..